# Promise with arbitrary third-party module

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am still new to Promise (as in [Promises/A+](http://promisesaplus.com/), not jQuery), and would like to convert some of my older client-side code into returning Promise so that downstream can be *thenable* instead having to pass the callback to upstream, in particular, anything to do with web storage and AJAX.

Problem is, the AJAX library ([Oboe](http://oboejs.com/)) I am using, it has a jQuery-style API but no `.then` method, which means I need to construct and return `new Promise` myself, but is following approach optimal? Can we do something using static `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` without wrapping a function? My example follows:

**old code**

```
function makeRequest(uri, callback) {

    var request = ajax(uri);

    request.fail(function(err) {
        // handle failure
    });

    request.done(function(res) {
        callback(res);
    });

}
```

**new code**

```
function makeRequest(uri) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var request = ajax(uri);

        request.fail(function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });

        request.done(function(res) {
            resolve(res);
        });

    });

}
```

**better code?**

```
function makeRequest(uri) {

    var request = ajax(uri);

    request.fail(function(err) {
        // handle failure
    });

    request.done(function(res) {
        // handle complete
    });

    // this won't work without third-party .then support
    return Promise.resolve(request);

}
```

(I intend to do this using native Promise and polyfill alone, but if there is library that has a helper for this, I am glad to take a look at their implementation.)

Comment: I haven't tried this before, but I think some promise libraries support jquery defers by simply wrapping around them, i.e. `new Promise(deferred)`, or some other syntax, have you tried this?

Comment: I am not using jQuery, so no `.then` on `request`, I don't think Promise.resolve is that magical, it probably treat it like a normal fulfill without waiting for callback to fire.

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap your Ajax function rather than just fixing it to return a real promise object so it has full-fledged promise support?

Comment: It's not a 100-line library, and it does unusual stuff: [oboejs](http://oboejs.com/). I prefer not to mess with it (since it's not mine)

Comment: You _have_ to use `new Promise` - if all the methods take the same kind of callback - you can extract that logic in a function. Closing as dupe of the canonical promisification question.